# android make changes in another fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have the following scenario:
[image]

In my main activity, I'm using sliding tabs using viewpager and fragmentpageradapter.

Suppose I have 2 tabs.
In Tab 2, on an event(say button press), I start a new activity using startActivityForResult.
Now, when I get back to Tab 2 from the new activity (in onActionResult), I want Tab 1 to get refreshed.

I'm currently doing it using getActivity.recreate()

Is this good way to do considering performance or is there any other way?

My main activity onCreate code is:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // setup action bar for tabs
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }

            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }
        };    

        ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.tab1)
                .setTabListener(tabListener);
        actionBar.addTab(tab, 0, false);

        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.tab2)
                .setTabListener(tabListener);
        actionBar.addTab(tab, 1, true);  

        // on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The viewpager adapter should hold the fragments.. so maybe use getItem(int position) then you get the instance of the fragment you want and you can have a method in the fragment which can update the view or data.. Recreating the whole fragment or activity will be a waste i guess.

Comment: @Thilek As I have mentioned in the question, I'm using viewpager

Comment: Tab1Fragment tab1Fragment  = (Tab1Fragment) fragmentpageradapter.getItem(0); Then call a method from  tab1Fragment wont work ? when you get back to previous activity and onActivityResult will be fired and can add the line there. View pager will hold instance of fragments based on the limit you set with viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(N number);.

Comment: @Thilek Isn't working, getting null object reference error when calling method in Tab1

Comment: maybe can you provide your activity and view pager implementation code.. then others can have a look..

Comment: @Thilek updated the question with main Activity code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89922/discussion-between-thilek-and-user5155835).